# Efficiency of random slicing on a numpy memory map

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I have a 20GB, 100k x 100k 'float16' 2D array as a datafile. I load it to memory as follows:

```
fp_read = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float16', mode='r', shape=(100000, 100000))
```

**I then attempt to read slices from it. The vertical slices I need to take are effectively random but the performance is very poor for this, or am I doing something wrong?**

---

Analysis:

I have compared with other forms of cross-sectional slicing, which is much better although I don't know why it should be:

```
%timeit fp_read[:,17000:17005]    # slice 5 consecutive cols
1.64 µs ± 16.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit fp_read[:,11000:11050:10]
1.67 µs ± 21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit fp_read[:,5000:6000:200]
1.66 µs ± 27.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit fp_read[:,0:100000:20000]    # slice 5 disperse cols
1.69 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit fp_read[:,[1,1001,27009,81008,99100]]     # slice 5 rand cols
32.4 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

a = np.arange(100000); b = np.array([1,1001,27009,81008,99100])
%timeit fp_read[np.ix_(a,b)]
18 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Even these timeit functions don't accurately capture the performance degradation, since:

```
import time
a = np.arange(100000)
cols = np.arange(100000)
np.random.shuffle(cols)
cols = np.sort(cols[:5])
t = time.time()
arr = fp_read[np.ix_(a,cols)]
print('Actually took: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - t))
Actually took: 24.5 seconds
```

Compared with:

```
t = time.time()
arr = fp_read[:,0:100000:20000]
print('Actually took: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - t))
Actually took 0.00024 seconds
```

Comment: At least for non contignous access to an array, I would recommend a chunked format like HDF5 (with a big chunk-cache)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The performance difference is explained by one key difference in "basic slicing and indexing" vs. "advanced indexing", [see these docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). The key line herein is

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view)).

How much the copy hurts can be seen from comparing `fp_read[:,5000:6000:200]` against `fp_read[:,5000:6000:200].copy()`.

Although making an array copy is always going to be slower than making a new view, it's especially bad for a memmap:

1. Reading from disk is relatively slow. The data needs to be read from disk to make the (in-memory) copy, while a *view* doesn't have to read any data at all! There is simply a new ndarray object created with new offset and stepsize (strides) parameters for the memory buffer.
2. The memory layout of your data is row-major order (vs. columns-major, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)). For accessing random columns this means that a sector has to be read from disk for every single value of data. Compare that to *contiguous* access, where you only  read one sector for every 256 values (assuming float16 and 512 byte sectors). With memory-mapped io this effect is even worse, because then data is read in blocks (memory pages) of 4kB, so 8 x 512 byte sectors.

Now we can also understand why the timeit results are not really representative: That particular part of the file is cached by the OS in memory.

Comment: This was very helpful. I restructures to row+major and made huge difference